How do i make a checkbox that disables an entry?
from tkinter import *
import string
import random
root = Tk()
root.title("PASSWORD GENERATOR")
#root.geometry("550x300+300+300")
root.config(bg="blue")
#root.resizable(False, False)

def clear_entry(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, END)

nazev = Label(root, text="Password Generator", font=("Comic Sans", 25, 'bold'), fg="#00b9ff", bg="blue",)
nazevletters = Label(root, text="How many letters would you like?",font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),bg="#00b9ff",)
nazevsymboly = Label(root, text="How many symbols would you like?",font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),bg="#00b9ff",)
nazevcisla = Label(root, text="How many numbers would you like?",font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),bg="#00b9ff",)

delkahesla = Entry(root, width=3, bg="#00eeff", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'))
delkahesla.insert(0, "...",)
delkahesla.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_entry)

Psymboly = Entry(root, width=3, bg="#00b9ff", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'))
Psymboly.insert(0, "...")
Psymboly.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_entry)

Pcisla = Entry(root, width=3, bg="#00eeff", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'))
Pcisla.insert(0, "...")
Pcisla.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_entry)
# tady vytvářím proměnné které kontrolují stav checkboxu
include_horni = BooleanVar(value=True) 
include_spodni = BooleanVar(value=True)
include_cisla = BooleanVar(value=True)
include_symboly = BooleanVar(value=True)
# Tady vytvářím checkbox a přiřadím mu proměnnou
horni_checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Include Lowercase", variable=include_horni, bg="blue", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'), fg="#00b9ff") 
spodni_checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Include Upercase", variable=include_spodni, bg="blue", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'),fg="#00b9ff") 
cisla_checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Include Numbers", variable=include_cisla, bg="blue", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'), fg="#00b9ff")
symboly_checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Include Symbols", variable=include_symboly, bg="blue", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'), fg="#00b9ff")

def generace(Ppismen,Psymbolu,Pcisel,usehorni,usespodni):
    abeceda = ""
    if usehorni:
        abeceda += string.ascii_uppercase
    if usespodni:
        abeceda += string.ascii_lowercase
    if not abeceda:
        return "Please select at least one letter option"
    
    cisla = string.digits
    symboly = string.punctuation
    heslo = []
    pocetpismen = Ppismen - Psymbolu - Pcisel

    if pocetpismen < 0:
        return "Invalid input: Too many symbols and numbers"
    
    if include_cisla.get() == True:
        Pcisla.config(state= "normal")
        for i in range(Pcisel):
            heslo.append(random.choice(cisla))

    elif include_cisla.get() == False:
        Pcisla.config(state= "disabled")


    
    if include_symboly.get() == True:
        Psymboly.config(state= "normal")
        for i in range(Psymbolu):
            heslo.append(random.choice(symboly))
    elif include_symboly.get() == False:
        Psymboly.config(state = "disabled")
    
    for i in range(pocetpismen):
        heslo.append(random.choice(abeceda))

    random.shuffle(heslo)
    STRheslo = ''.join(heslo)
    return STRheslo

def onclick():
    while True:
        heslo = []  # Clear the list each time the button is clicked
        vysledek.delete(0, END)  # Clear the entry widget each time the button is clicked
        try:
            x = int(delkahesla.get())
            if x > 8 and x <= 256:
                pass
            elif x < 8 or x > 256:
                vysledek.insert(0, "Password must be 8-256 characters")
                break
            pass
            y = int(Psymboly.get())
            if y > 0:
                pass
            elif y <= 0:
                vysledek.insert(0, "All passwords should have atleast 1 symbol")
                break
            pass
            z = int(Pcisla.get())
            if z > 0:
                pass
            elif z <= 0:
                vysledek.insert(0, "All passwords should have atleast 1 number")
                break
            pass
            if y + z > x:
                vysledek.insert(0, "Symbols and numbers exceed total length")
                break
            pass
                 
        except ValueError:
            vysledek.insert(0, "Please enter valid numbers")
            return

    
    
        vysledek.insert(0, generace(x,y,z,include_spodni.get(),include_horni.get()))
        break
    

vysledek = Entry(root, width=50,bg="#00eeff",font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'))
tlacitko = Button(root, width=15, text="Generate!", command=onclick, fg="black", bg="#00b9ff", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'))


nazev.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
nazevsymboly.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=EW)
nazevcisla.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=EW)
nazevletters.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=EW)
delkahesla.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=EW)
Psymboly.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2,sticky=EW)
Pcisla.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2,sticky=EW)
horni_checkbox.grid(row=4, column=0)
spodni_checkbox.grid(row=4, column=1)
cisla_checkbox.grid(row=5, column=0)
symboly_checkbox.grid(row=5, column=1)
tlacitko.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2)
vysledek.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()

In this code i managed to make it so that if you uncheck the include numbers (or include symbols) it disables the entry but only if you click generate not instantly (i want it instantly).
i know i should probably make it a own function but how? when do i call that function? im just confused any help is appriciated.

You can use command option to execute a function to enable or disable corresponding entry widget based on the check state.
cisla_checkbox = Checkbutton(
    root, text="Include Numbers", variable=include_cisla,
    bg="blue", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'), fg="#00b9ff",
    command=lambda: Pcisla.config(state=(NORMAL if include_cisla.get() else DISABLED))
)
symboly_checkbox = Checkbutton(
    root, text="Include Symbols", variable=include_symboly,
    bg="blue", font=("Arial", 15, 'bold'), fg="#00b9ff",
    command=lambda: Psymboly.config(state=(NORMAL if include_symboly.get() else DISABLED))
)

Then you don't need to enable or disable entry widgets inside generace().
Note also that you don't need the while loop inside onclick():
def onclick():
    heslo = []  # Clear the list each time the button is clicked
    vysledek.delete(0, END)  # Clear the entry widget each time the button is clicked
    try:
        x = int(delkahesla.get())
        if x < 8 or x > 256:
            vysledek.insert(0, "Password must be 8-256 characters")
            return

        y = z = 0

        if include_symboly.get():
            y = int(Psymboly.get())
            if y <= 0:
                vysledek.insert(0, "All passwords should have atleast 1 symbol")
                return

        if include_cisla.get():
            z = int(Pcisla.get())
            if z <= 0:
                vysledek.insert(0, "All passwords should have atleast 1 number")
                return

        if y + z > x:
            vysledek.insert(0, "Symbols and numbers exceed total length")
            return

    except ValueError:
        vysledek.insert(0, "Please enter valid numbers")
        return

    vysledek.insert(0, generace(x,y,z,include_spodni.get(),include_horni.get()))

